# Unable to connect to SQL database - C#, VS2012, SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

**I have SQL Server 2005, 2008 and 2012 installed on my Windows 7 64bit PC.**

[image]

---

**Here is my Configuration Manager, and I do see that the Agent is Stopped... not sure if this is required.  I've split it out into two images so the size shows up larger**

[image]

[image]

---

**Here is what is shown in the VS2012 Database Explorer window.  This is a SQL Server 2012 database**

[image]

---

**Here is my code**

```
string selectSql = "select * from Tasks";

string connectionString = "Data Source=adamssqlserver;Database=master;Integrated Security=True;";

using (var cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSql, cn))
{
    cn.Open(); // this is the line that throws the error message.
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
            //do something
    }
}
```

**As noted, the cn.Open(); line is what throws the error message shown below**

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: string connectionString = "Data Source=lpc192\adamssqlserver;Database=master;Integrated Security=True;";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Data Source=adamssqlserver
```

is wrong, should be:

```
Data Source=lpc193\adamssqlserver
```

This can be seen in the Server Explorer screenshot you attached. Your connection string is looking for a computer calls "adamssqlserver", whereas your database is a named instance on your computer, which is called "lpc193", so is addressed as lpc193\adamssqlserver

Comment: Ah! I had tried that before but only with a single slash... then gave up on that thought.  I used two back slashes this time (to escape) and now it works! thank you very much!!!

Comment: Ah right, you can get around that by prefixing your connectionstring with an @ symbol, please see: http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-literal

Comment: No worries. Please feel free to accept the answer in case any body else has the same problem.

Comment: Will do!  It won't let me accept for 4 more minutes though, lol.  Also would you change the lpc192 to lpc193, no big deal but very slight difference :)  thanks again!